# why setTimeout is not executed in javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a function to sleep in javascript like below:

```
var is_sleep = true;
function sleep(time){
  if (is_sleep){
    is_sleep = false;
    setTimeout("sleep(time)", time);
  }else{
    is_sleep = true;
  }
}
sleep(3000);
```

However it runs through the statements for is_sleep=true, doesn't run through is_sleep=false statements and doesn't sleep any more.

Could someone tell what the reason is?　Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's likely that `setTimeout` is being called, but the string passed to it is failing, as the scope will no longer contain `time`, which you're referencing. Try replacing that line with this:

```
setTimeout(function() { sleep(time); }, time);
```

...which defines a closure, which uses the correct scope. You could also try this:

```
setTimeout(sleep, time, time);
```

...which will pass `time` as an argument to `sleep`.

Comment: thank you very much. Could you tell me why time in "sleep(time)" is not the time scope? i don't understand it even though it worked, :-)

Comment: @ywenbo: Sure. When you pass a string as a parameter to `setTimeout`, when the timeout goes off, it will `eval` it in `window`'s scope. `time` won't be in `window`'s scope; it will be in `sleep`'s now-inaccessible scope. If you use a closure, it inherits the scope from where it's defined. If you use the second method, then it passes `sleep` as a reference and tells `setTimeout` to pass `time` as an argument to it.

Comment: very strong and clear explanation, you're nice and great, i very appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) runs [asynchronously](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O) meaning it's not blocking your code execution.  Perhaps you knew that, but the function will never live up to the name you chose for it.

First call `sleep(3000);` calls the sleep function, making the `is_sleep` variable `false`, setting a timer, and then immediately returns code execution (to whatever comes after `sleep(3000);` ;))

If `setTimeout` was called properly (`setTimeout(sleep,time,time);`), after 3 seconds, the function would again be called setting `is_sleep` back to `true`.